# Use preg_match to find a specified string?

Tags: php

I have a very big table in database (55MB) holding data for certain stuff. Each field has their own id and description fields. What I want to do is to get with PHP the description value. Okay, that I can do. But, the problem comes when I attempt to find and replace certain 'words'.

The description value can be following:

> Connection timed out with error message $s1.

Now, this '$s1' can be pretty much anything. But I want to find from the description field every word beginning with '$' and replace them with correct values. In that case, I would want to find the $s1 part, then set it into an array and then replace it with a real value. Some examples what else $s1 can be: $s19593, $d30, $s2, $a, $r, $z, $o4... and so on. Basically the number after $s can vary from 1 to 70000. I can put the rest values if just someone could point me into right direction and teach me a bit ofcourse.

Oh, and the description value also can be following:

> Connection failed in $o52 with $d2 $s952.

Very annoying table imo but no can do. I just can't edit every single field in the table (51,000 fields).

The best regards

EDIT: Here's a sample code!

```
include "../config.php";

function getErrorValue($id)
{
   if (empty($id) || $id == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   mysql_select_db("$database", $connect);
   $query_geterrordata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbc_error WHERE id='$id'");
   while ($row_geterrordata = mysql_fetch_array($query_geterrordata))
   {
      if (!empty($row_geterrordata['field170']))
      {
         $temp_err = $row_geterrordata['field170']; // description field
         //$err = preg_match   don't know how to continue here
      }
   }

   if (!empty($err))
   {
      return $err;
   }
   else
   {
      return "Error fetching the code.";
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's often advisable you show a little code example even if it does not yet fully work for you but so that it is clear (next to the general description you've been given), with what you've got the concrete programming problem.

Comment: Forgot it totally, added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will pull out all the variables starting with a $:

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[^ ]+)/', $temp_err, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Otherwise that would be good but there are over 30,000 different descriptions, and not them all have the variable in same place

Comment: Apparently with that, it only fetches $s, missing the number after.

Comment: sorry, missed a symbol when I copied it on to stack overflow, I've added a "+" in

Comment: Thank you for answering. Checkout the results: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xl68lk it prints the arrays weirdly. I changed the $ symbols to # symbols due to the site expects them to be PHP variables.

Comment: Hi, that is the expected output.  If you notice in my code I am printing $matches[1], not just $matches.  $matches[0] always contains the whole string matched.  BTW, use single quotes ('$xxx') around your strings so that it doesn't try to interpret $ signs as variables.